# controlling text on a page using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I need to control the work 'paypal' in this snipet of code.

```
<tr class="total">
<td class="text-right">Total inc VAT: &nbsp;</td>
<td class="text-center">£0.00</td> ***this is the basket total***
</tr>
```

AND

```
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" value="paypal" id="pgbtnpaypal" onclick="hideCCForm()">
PayPal ***this is the wording to change***
</label>
```

I am unable to add any classes or IDs to the second snippet of code, so the above needs to stay as it is.

I need a conditional statement that says;

'If basket total = £0.00 then change the wording 'Paypal' to 'Free Basket'.

Are there any JS wizards that can help me achieve this please?

Thanks in advance

D

Comment: Where's the code that sets the ```£0.00``` value?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, It will be helpful if you can provide more details about your environment. Are you using JQuery? Angular? React or something else. Answers will be different based on that

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```js
(function () {
  isFree(document.querySelector("tr.total td.text-center").innerHTML);
})();

function isFree(cost) {
  var a = '<input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" value="paypal" id="pgbtnpaypal" onclick="hideCCForm()">';
  var el = document.getElementById('pgbtnpaypal').parentNode;
  if(cost === 0 || cost == "£0.00") {
    el.innerHTML = a + 'Free Basket';
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="total">
    <td class="text-right">Total inc VAT: &nbsp;</td>
    <td class="text-center">£0.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" value="paypal" id="pgbtnpaypal" onclick="hideCCForm()">
PayPal
</label>
```